# Differences between Xerces-C++ v2 and v3 branches

Tags: c++, xml, xerces-c

Checking the [Xerces-C++ webpage](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/), I saw there are two major branches of the parser:
**Version 2.8.0** and **Version 3.1.1**

1. What are the main differences between those two? (couldn't find any summary on their page)
2. Which one should I choose for starting a brand new Visual Studio
   2010 C++ project?

Thanks for any help

Comment: A quick google showed up this: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/migrate-archive-3.html#Migrateto300 maybe it helps.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Thanks for the link. This answers my first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. already answered by PlasmaHH with [migrate to v3](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/migrate-archive-3.html#Migrateto300)
2. There are [pre-built binary distributions](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/download.cgi)  and [ready-made project files](http://apache.lauf-forum.at//xerces/c/3/sources/xerces-c-3.1.1.zip) for Visual Studio 2010 available only for Xerces-C++ v3.

   Xerces-C++ v2 supports Visual Studio up to version 2005.

   Therefore I suggest to go with  **Xerces-C++ v3**.